# How is one's gotra relevant today?

Tags: gotra

Besides marriage (i.e. not marrying a person of the same gotra), how is gotra significant today? Does one need to perform a ritual related to gotra?

Comment: Before every ritual we must perform Sankalpa and in it, besides other many things, the Gotra has to be mentioned/specified.

Comment: Maybe scriptures can be referenced here for religious ceremonial matters. Other than that it has no significance and is more an archaic term.

Comment: Ofcourse it is relevant. Just because few/many decide to downplay its importance does not render it as irrelevant.

Comment: @Carmensandiego again, to consider it relevant or not is a personal opinion.

Comment: @Vivikta - And that's why I've voted to close this question. Gotra is as significant or insignificant today as it was in past